# printf(string) vs. printf("%s", string)

Tags: c, printf

I'm writing a proxy server, and I ran into a curious bug that I hoped someone would be able to explain.

I'm receiving the first line of a GET request from client. For example, the client would send the request:

```
GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random HTTP/1.0
Host: en.wikipedia.org
...
```

And I would forward this request to the server.

However, with certain web addresses, I would encounter a problem:

```
GET http://map.media6degrees.com/orbserv/curl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.masteringemacs.org%2Farticles[trunc] HTTP/1.0
```

I read this line into `char buffer[MAXLINE_LENGTH]`, which is long enough to hold the string.

When I print the received get request with

```
printf(buffer);
```

The printed string is:

```
GET http://map.media6degrees.com/orbserv/hbpix?pixId=2869&curl=http0X0.0000000000015P-10220.0000000.000000www.masteringemacs.org0.000000articles0.00000020100.000000110.000000010.000000running-shells-in-emacs-overview204741995430849962482228271154502456423284733956118041206315879167624419264810411254941012469231829496710329852458403099883653794777355548418601638730167027236864.000000 HTTP/1.0
```

It appears the %3A, %2F, etc. have been string formatted.

When I run `printf("%s", buffer);`, I get the correct and expected output

EDIT: I understand why this is occurring; I'm interested in why this is occurring this way. 
Are the values that printf is "string formatting" coming from some arbitrary area on the stack?
Are the %3A et al valid format strings?

Comment: See the `%`'s in the data...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) If you look at the function prototype, you'll see that printf() expects a format string, and zero or more arguments.  So, strictly speaking, "printf(string)" is *not* correct:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdio.h>

       int printf(const char *format, ...);
       int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
       int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
       int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const  char  *format,
       ...);
```

2) The first argument *will* be interpreted as a format string, and any "%XXX" entries it found will be interpreted as place holders.  Which it sounds like is exactly what's happening :)

3) The solution, of course, is `printf ("%s", string)`

4) Or using `puts(string)` instead :)

Comment: @yzb3 - you're absolutely correct :)  I edited my response accordingly :)

Comment: `puts(string)` isn't _exactly_ the same since it appends a newline.  `fputs(string, stdout)` should work, though.

Comment: BTW, I've read that gcc will replace `printf("%s", string)` with `fputs(string, stdout)` as an optimization.

Comment: Right, this is what I figured. So, in that case, where are the other values coming from?

Comment: Joshua Green - to repeat: you're absolutely correct.  @Eagle - argh!!!!!  Strictly speaking, you're not *supposed* to have just a string argument.  If you do, it better not have "%" signs in it.  But if you do, then gcc is nice enough to substitute "fputs()".  This is *compiler specific*.  You *cannot* rely on it.  And clearly, it doesn't work that way in your compiler :)

Comment: is this not a legitimate question? I understand this is undefined behavior, passing a format string without any format arguments, which allows it to get past gcc without any warnings.
so where do the garbage values I am seeing come from?

Comment: Cool - you *got* it!  "Undefined behavior" - that's exactly right.  And remember that your URL-encoded string (http%3A%2F%...) *does* have format characters - whether you *intended* it to or not.  Is it clear yet?

Comment: Printf is a variatic function, that takes a format string and any number of arguments, and then that walks the stack at runtime to retrieve the 'arguments' corresponding to the %s, %d, etc. This is a type of attack on a system.

Answer (score 5):

Never use an input string as a format parameter to printf.

To work correctly, it must have no "%..." items. These are special commands to the printf() function to access the parameters list.

Answer (score 1):

In the `format` argument to the `printf` and `scanf` family of functions `%` is treated as an escape character. You raw input has some of them and `printf` is trying to interpret them.

Comment: Not to be picky, but perhaps "metacharacter" might be a better term.  "\n" is an example of an "escape character".  So is "%%":  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Answer (score 0):

If you use printf(string), then the printed string may be NULL.
That's the only problem that I see with this.The printf function reads all va_list arguments according to the format provided, so it may crash if you pass a NULL pointer.
With LLVM 4.1 I get this warning:

```
Format string is not a literal string (potentially insecure)
```

This is my personal opinion: if you are sure that the string isn't NULL (maybe verify it through an assertion, and then remove that assertion in the release), then you could go with printf(string).If you are not totally sure that the string may be NULL or invalid, then use a literal string.